# Terraform: split function in output gives error when count is used while creating a resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am creating a resource by using count in it. When I use split function in the output it gives me error while normal output where split is not used just works fine.

I am running on stack=dev right now. I expect the same resource to not get created on dev stack but it should get created in prod stack. I am trying to write a code in such a way

Below is the piece of code which gives error

```
data "aws_cloudformation_stack" "some_name" {
      count = (local.stack == "dev" ? 0 : 1)
      name = "${local.stack}_some_name"
    }

output "public_alb_subnets" {
  value = split(",", "${data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name[*].outputs["PublicElbSubnets"]}")
 
}
```

It gives me error

Error: Invalid function argument

```
  on managed_alb.tf line 138, in output "public_alb_subnets":
 138:   value = split(",", "${data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name[*].outputs["PublicElbSubnets"]}")
    |----------------
    | data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name is empty tuple

Invalid value for "str" parameter: string required.
```

However below works

```
output "public_alb_security_groups" {
  value = [
    data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name[*].outputs["PublicElbSecurityGroup"],
    data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name[*].outputs["InternalElbSecurityGroup"]
  ]
}
```

I tried many different options on the web but none of them worked. What I am doing wrong here. Even using count.index or 0 in place of * doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you don't have any outputs in the stack? Why do you think you have?

Comment: Yes I am running in on dev and it gives me error. I expect the same resource to not get created on dev stack but it should get created in prod stack. So basically on dev stack there should be no output and on prod there should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your output also conditional, based on your `dev` or `prod` environments:

```
output "public_alb_subnets" {
  value = length(data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name) > 0 ? split(",", "${data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name[*].outputs["PublicElbSubnets"]}") : null 
}
```

Comment: When I use it on the prod stack it gives me error  Invalid function argument 
:48    on alb.tf line 138, in output "public_alb_subnets":
 138:   value = length(data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name) > 0 ? split(",", data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name[*].outputs["PublicElbSubnets"]) : null
  |---------------- data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name is tuple with 1 element

Comment: @user27111987 You would have to just output entire `data.aws_cloudformation_stack.some_name` and check what actually it is.